# Cannot execute AWS Sagemaker Notebook

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I cannot execute sagemaker notebook anymore.
The following error occurs.

```
Failed to start kernel
An error occurred (ThrottlingException) when calling the CreateApp operation (reached max retries: 4): 
Rate exceeded
```

I checked my app list and there are only two.
One app is trying to delete but never stops, this could be one of the problem.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0iqo.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Happened to me too. Contact support and ask them to delete the kernel behind the scenes.